# No camera found in blender

Tags: camera

When I open Blender, I usually see a lamp and a cube, but when I opened a minecraft rig .blend, it wasn't there. I tried using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, but it didn't do anything.

I clicked something that I can't remember, and it said no camera found.

Comment: I saw this in the Hot Network Questions and immediately thought of [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zcdoa0XCFo).

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you are in *Pose Mode*. To change that, simply click on a different object, say the minecraft guy (not the rig). Or in the 3D view header switch to *Object mode*, then you will be able to add a camera.

Here is a picture of the add menu in pose mode. As you can see the camera, along with other object types are grayed out.
[image: add menu in pose mode]

Answer (score 5):

What happened, is that you opened the minecraft rig .blend, and it didn't have a camera in it.

First, make sure that you are in object mode, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and click Camera.

Then just move it to where you want it.

Comment: When I press shift+A the camera is grey, so I cannot click that option

Comment: Could you post a .blend then? That doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37717

Comment: @Noobbb See David's answer. It's because you aren't in Object Mode. (I added it to my answer also)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to a problem like this is to save the blend file you want to open to someplace on your system where you'll subsequently be able to find it. Then open a new instance of Blender, select the "Open" option in the file menu item, and navigate to where the file you want to open was saved. At the bottom of the navigation bar on the extreme left of the file browser window is a panel "Open Blender file". If it minimized (that is, the triangle at the leftmost end of the line is oriented with a flat edge to the left, and a point to the right, click the triangle to maximize the panel. You will see to sub-menu items, each to the right of a checkbox, one is "Load UI", which defaults to checked. Uncheck that box, and the file will be loaded with the current Blender UI.

By the way, the other item in this submenu, "Trusted source", should be unchecked, unless you know for certain that the file is from a trusted source. Checking this box means that any scripts which are set to autorun in the file will, indeed, autorun without you knowing for certain whether you want them to run or not. Making sure the box is unchecked allows you to verify that you do, indeed, want the scripts to run.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to uncheck Trusted Source. It usually get's enabled afterwards anyway. This is especially true for rigs where python drivers may have been used.

Comment: Checking trusted source means any scripts in the file that are set to run at startup, run. If there's malware in the scripts, no chance to stop them. Unchecking trusted source means the user loading the software gets to choose whether (or when) the scripts run, giving a chance to weed out the malware.